# about Randomized-select algorithm

Tags: java, data-structures

I have this array  `A = <3,2,9,0,7,5,4,8,6,1>` and I want to write all its worst partitions are these correct?thanks

```
a1 = <0,2,9,3,7,5,4,8,6,1>
a2 = <1,9,3,7,5,4,8,6,2>
a3 = <2,3,7,5,4,8,6,9>
a4 = <3,7,5,4,8,6,9>
a5 = <4,5,7,8,6,9>
a6 = <5,7,8,6,9>
a7 = <6,8,7,9>
a8 = <7,8,9>
a9 = <8,9>
a10 = <9>
```

Comment: Is "worst partition" a technical term that I'm not familiar with, or does this question need to be more specific?

Comment: worst random partition means that your random pivot be the less one and make a partition like 0:n-1

Comment: for a1 the random pivot is "0" which makes the worst partitions(one partition has zero element and the other one has "n-1" elements.

Comment: Are you asking if the partitions are correct, or how to write those partitions?

Comment: Is this in context of another algorithm? (random pivot sounds like a term used in a randomized qsort...)

Comment: Sounds like you want to remove the smallest value.  You could use a PriorityQueue and keep removing from the head.

Comment: for example I have used randomized select algorithm and because I am not lucky always the random pivot will be the less one and makes the worst partitions for me(one of partitions will be like 0:n-1) and I have just written all those worst partitions that will accrue when I use this algorithm!!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want to display the worst sequence of partitions of a given array (partitions like the ones performed by [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)).

In this case you can sort the array, and then display all "tails" of the array, starting from index 0 and ending with index n-1.

In your example, the sorted array is:

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

and then the tails are:

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

....

[8,9]

[9]

If you display all partitions, then this is an O(n^2) algorithm (obviously can't be improved). If you only need to display the pivots, you can do it in O(n*log n).

Comment: yes you get my meaning well but in the randomized select algorithm we do not sort our array!!!

Comment: I was not trying to implement the "randomized select algorithm" (do you refer to finding the k-th smallest number of a collection??). I only suggested a way to print the worst sequence of partitions in the sense of quicksort partitions.

Comment: @martin1234: Yes, it looks like your sequence is the worst one, according to your definition.